# if not line.startswith - give to much single quotes and line bracks

Tags: python

In my attempt to get an Apache log parser, I try to filter IP adresses, with the following code:

```
for r in log: 
    host_line = "'",r['host'],"'"
    for line in host_line:
        if not line.startswith("178.255.20.20"):
            print line.strip()
```

The result of this code is:

```
p4fdf6780.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
'
'
79.223.103.128
'
'
p4fdf6780.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
'
'
```

With `line.replace("'", "")` I remove the single quotes.

```
print line.replace("'", "")
```

The result:

```
p4fdf6780.dip0.t-ipconnect.de


79.223.103.128


p4fdf6780.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
```

This leaves me with the two line breaks.

How can a avoid those line breaks?
And is there a work around, or a better solution - more pythonic way to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your code like below. You don't need to go for a `replace` function.

```
for r in log: 
    host_line = "'",r['host'],"'"
    for line in host_line:
        if not line.startswith("178.255.20.20"):
            if not line == "'":
                print line.strip()
```

Comment: Thank this was the simplest imput to my own code. And because of that I will vote your answer. Help me out how to do that?

Comment: accept an answer which helps you lot and upvote the answers which work.

Answer (score 3):

What *do* you want the program to do? What is the intended purpose of the `for line in host_line` loop?

If you're just looking to print hosts other than 178.255.20.20, would the following not work?

```
for r in log: 
    host = str(r['host']).strip() # not sure if the str() is required, depends on type of r['host']
    if not host.startswith("178.255.20.20"):
        print host
```

Comment: the problem is that he gets empty lines when filtering the quote '

Comment: Yes but why add the quotes and use the `host_line` list in the first place? If you need to quote the host name while printing, do it in the last print command: `print "'%s'" % host`

Comment: Yes i also was looking for a way to make the r['host'] as a sting with str(r['host']) but could not find my way around. With out the str it is also working. So thanks for the lesson and making a smaller code.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use bash and a dedicated search tool like [Ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or just a standard grep which will make it really fast because it is C:

```
grep -v "178.255.20.20" your_log.txt | grep -v -E "^'"
```

If you need to stick to python then try to better use strip so that it removes also the quote character and print the line only if not empty:

```
for r in log: 
    host_line = "'",r['host'],"'"
    for line in host_line:
        if not line.startswith("178.255.20.20"):
            line = line.strip("'\n")
            if len(line) > 0:  print line
```

Comment: Thank for bringing bash under my attention. I tried your grep and it works for me. I will see if I go on that way. No i do not need to stick to python directly. It is more that i like to learn more with Python. Thanks for the python strip and len lesson.